# Django overriding detail view get method

Tags: django, detailview, getmethod

This is my post detail view and it works perfectly.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'posts/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        content['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()

        return context
```

However, when I add get method to the view it does not work anymore.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # how to return here so that it works exactly like before
```

After adding get method `get_queryset` and `get_context_data` do not gets called automatically and the context is empty in the template. So what would be the get method so that it works exactly like before?

**EDIT**
My target is to do something like this

```
if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('comments/detail.html')  # ajax reply with html data
    return HttpResponse(html)
 return render 'posts/detail.html'
```

So where do I put this code and still want to keep call all methods such as `get_queryset` and `get_context_data` to be called automatically?

Comment: You haven't explained what you want to do. Why are you overriding the get method? What are you doing in that method?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, since the `get(..)` is already implemented to trigger the `get_context_data`, etc. and render the template with that context, so by overriding it, you remove the boilerplate logic.

Answer (score 6):

The idea of views like a `DetailView`, `ListView`, etc. is that it implements the *boilerplate logic* for you. So it has defined a function `def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` that is used to render the logic. You can usually tweak a few things by specifying the `model`, `queryset`, etc. without reimplementing the entire view.

For a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), the logic is implemented in the `BaseDetailView` you can inspect the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/detail.py#L105):

> ```
> class BaseDetailView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
>     """A base view for displaying a single object."""
>     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.object = self.get_object()
>         context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
>         return self.render_to_response(context)
> ```

Comment: Please take a  look at my edit. I find most solutions on internet where get method is overriden. But this is not working for me.

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk: but that is usually for function-based views.

Answer (score 2):

One general piece of advice I want to share:
Before overriding any attribute, one must have deep knowledge of what is the significance of that attribute (callable or not callable). This advice applies to any language or framework. Suppose when someone overrides the  `get` in Django, all the methods that are being called from `get` will not be invoked unless one invokes that from overridden `get`. So you should see the source of `get` and observe that methods are called from that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old thread, but the solution seems simple: you need to call the original `get()` method at the end of your overriding `get()` method by calling something like:

```
return super(PostDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```